# Postman sees more cookies than python request

Tags: python, http, cookies, python-requests, postman

When sending a GET request with postman I can see the following cookies.
[image]
Doing the same thing with python requests module I don't get this CP cookie.

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.post('https://wikipedia.org')
    cookies = session.cookies.get_dict()
    print(cookies)
```

Output:

```
{'WMF-Last-Access-Global': '12-Sep-2017', 'GeoIP': 'XXXXXX', 'WMF-Last-Access': '12-Sep-2017'}
```

Why so? Is there a way to get that cookie with python?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your results with postman. I'm getting the same cookies with the requests library and postman. With that being said, you should read more into when Compact Policy (CP) fields are sent as part of a cookie here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Browser_settings